# Adding terms to a function in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I have recently made a post with a very similar question. Unfortunately, I did not give enough context to what I want to achieve.

I want to write a loop that adds terms to a function. It is important that I end up with a function in order to find the derivative at a later point in time.

I have previously written loops that add values to vectors. When trying to do the same thing with an empty function it does not add elements but it just redefines the function.

Example of what I mean when adding to a vector:

```
x <- c()
i <- 1
while(length(x)<10){
  x <- c(x,i) 
  i <- i + 1
}
```

My goal is now to do the same thing but storing additional elements in a funtion.
My attempt at doing this is currently only redefining the function and also not using numerical values for i and C but keeping them as a slot.

My code:

```
x <- function(r){}
i <- 1
s <- c(0.01,0.02,0.03)
C <- 5
while(i <= length(s)){
  x <- function(r){
    x + C/(1+r)^i
  }
  i <- i+1
}
```

The desired outcome of this loop would be a function that looks as follows.

```
x = function(r){5/(1+r)^1 + 5/(1+r)^2 + 5/(1+r)^3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function by creating a string and then use `eval(parse(x))`, to evaluate that string.

```
createfunction <- function(C, s) {

    output <-  ""

    for(i in 1:length(s)) {

        if(i == 1) {
            start <- paste0("function(r){", C, "/1+r^",i, " + ")
        } else if(i > 1 & i < length(s)) {
            output <- paste0(output, C, "/1+r^",i, " + ") 
        } else {
            output <- eval(parse(text = paste0(start, output, C, "/1+r^",i, "}")))
        }
    }
    return(output)
}


createfunction(6, c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02))
```